# cannot access my springboot app from the browser

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have been wqritting springboot app but all of a sudden its giving error page syaing, "This site can’t be reached
The webpage at http://localhost:6000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_UNSAFE_PORT"

but the server is running on the same port, below is part of my stacktrace

> 2018-10-23 11:38:49.795 DEBUG 3128 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.s.w.s.resource.ResourceUrlProvider     : Found resource handler
>   mapping: URL pattern="/**", locations=[ServletContext resource [/],
>   class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource
>   [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource
>   [public/]],
>   resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@69f5c90c]
>   2018-10-23 11:38:50.030  INFO 3128 --- [  restartedMain]
>   s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s):
>   6000 (http) 2018-10-23 11:38:50.030 DEBUG 3128 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [server.ports]
>   PropertySource with highest search precedence 2018-10-23 11:38:50.047 
>   INFO 3128 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.UserAccountRegistrationApplication
>   : Started UserAccountRegistrationApplication in 13.01 seconds (JVM
>   running for 14.289)

i dont what causes this, thank you

Comment: Which IDE are you using? and where did you configure the port number?

Comment: i am using eclipse below is my application.properties file

Comment: server.address=127.0.0.1
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.port=6000

Comment: can you please check if the port is already occupied by some other application? if yes, then kill the process. *lsof -i :6000* would work for MacOS

Comment: thats the only process using the port

Comment: kill the process and try re-running the application. Though, this would be a temporary solution. Need to find out the root cause.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? I just found out that you need to enable that port for your browser. Here is the link for your reference, https://superuser.com/questions/188006/how-to-fix-err-unsafe-port-error-on-chrome-when-browsing-to-unsafe-ports

Comment: thanx alot prinali it had to do with unsafe ports .. its now solved